# Read serial input to a C variable

Tags: c, input, serial-port, arduino

Hi I am trying to read serial input (from an Arduino) from a C- program. I am able to send data to the Arduino using

```
system("echo -n \"data\" > /dev/ttyUSB0");
```

but I cannot figure out how to get an input from the same Arduino to a string in the c-program (which is to be processed within the program). How do i do this?

Comment: read `man termios`. And `system("echo -n \"data\" > /dev/ttyUSB0")` isn't a C code!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it would be a lot less ugly to open `/dev/ttyUSB0` as a file and write to it than to rely on `system()`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no point in calling system for such communication. You can access the serial port pretty much like a file by using the functions `open`, `read`, `write` `ioctl` and `close`.

Just pass `/dev/ttyUSB0` to open as the file to be opened. You only need ioctl in case you want to modify the connection settings (like baudrate or parity or stuff)

You can have a look at http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/index.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

Reading 255 bytes from /dev/ttyUSB0 at baud rate 230400:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BAUDRATE B230400

void main() {
   int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
   struct termios options;
   tcgetattr(fd, &options);
   cfsetispeed(&options, BAUDRATE);
   cfsetspeed(&options, BAUDRATE);
   options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
   tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

   if (fd == -1)
       printf("Cannot open port /dev/ttyUSB0\n");
   char buf[255];
   int n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
   printf("%d bytes read\n%s\n", n, buf);
}
```